# Unknown column in 'on clause' with inner join

Tags: mysql

My Tables

**ea_users**

> | id | email | phone | id_cellcarrier |

**ea_cellcarrier**

> | id | cellurl |

I want:

> | email | phone | cellurl |

My SQL statement

```
SELECT ea_users.email, ea_users.phone_number, ea_cellcarrier.cellurl 
FROM ea_users, ea_cellcarrier 
INNER JOIN ea_cellcarrier AS c2
ON ea_users.id_cellcarrier = c2.id
```

I get:
Unknown column 'ea_users.id_cellcarrier' in 'on clause'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't mix the "lazy" join syntax with explicit `join`. choose one style or the other, but not both.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be rewritten

```
SELECT e.email, e.phone, c2.cellurl 
FROM ea_users e
INNER JOIN ea_cellcarrier c2
ON e.id_cellcarrier = c2.id
```

Also, it looks like the column name for ea_users is `phone`, right?

Answer (score -1):

This worked:

```
SELECT ea_users.email, ea_users.phone_number, ea_cellcarrier.cellurl 
FROM ea_users 
INNER JOIN ea_cellcarrier
ON ea_users.id_cellcarrier = ea_cellcarrier.id
```